# Android urbanairship-sdk build Error

Tags: android

When I build my urbanairship Demo,error happend.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':urbanairship-sdk:templatizeNativeBridge'.
```

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'src/main/js/templatize''

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in 7.2.3. We had a script that would generate a class that was not compatible on PCs.

Answer (score 0):

it is stable version of urbanairship sdk

```
  dependencies {
        compile 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:7.2.2'
    }
```